# Output value with TimeSpan without seconds

Tags: c#, format, output, timespan

I ran into a problem. I have property

```
TimeSpan StartedStudy {get; set;}
```

I need just initialize this property using **TimeSpan**

How I make it.

```
StartedStudy = TimeSpan.FromHours(10);
```

*Output:* **10:00:00**

What I have ? I have 10(hours), 00(minutes) and 00(seconds),
but I don't need output seconds, I need

*Output:* **10:00**  without seconds.

**Warning:** How to cut seconds without converting to string ?

Comment: Without converting to a string, what is the difference between 10:00:00 and 10:00?

Comment: Where are you actually outputting StartedStudy? Most likely, you actually do want a string, you just want it at output only.

Comment: @Broom, I just want to see output in format hours and minutes, without seconds.

Comment: @Broom In the Backend part I initialize property for the testing output values into the frontend

Comment: Can you show us that?

Answer (score 1):

The `TimeSpan` and `DateTime` types are not stored internally as you see them. Internally, they are just numbers like `Integer` and `Long`. Wherever you see the `TimeSpan` as `10:00:00`, you are actually looking at its string representation. There is no concept of hours, minutes, and seconds separately in the `TimeSpan`, so you cannot remove one of them. They're all one single number. You'll have to convert them to string before you can display them in any human readable way.

Comment: brilliant answer, thank you!
But how I can do it without getting errors likes "cannot implicitly convert type" ?

Comment: Your question is not clear, I need more details to answer. If it is related to your original question, then edit it and add the new details. If it is unrelated, then open a new question.